# Displaying an image on WooCommerce Order Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am working on a pharmacy ecommerce mobile based project where a customer can create an order for some medicines and could additionally submit the prescription as a photo taken through the mobile cam. The back-end side for the project is based on WordPress and Woo-commerce. The prescription photo will be submitted as part of the order meta data and I will save it to the uploads file and I already did that. What I need is being able to render that submitted prescription when viewing the order in all order view pages and I do not know how to do that as I am completely new to WordPress and especially Woo-commerce so can anyone help me telling me the steps I can follow what hooks I can use to get the job done!

I searched for available hooks and I found a woo-commerce visual guide it helped a bit, however, I do not know how to get the current displayed order and specifically gets it meta data

To be able to view an order related prescription photo if any on all woocommerce order view pages

Comment: It depends on how are you storing the data in the order meta. If you can provide some info about, it would help

Comment: I got the image in the request as a base 64 encoded in the meta data key/value pairs array property, before doing the actual save to the database I manipulate that encoded value. I search within the request meta array for a certain key, getting the encoded value, decode it, save it to disk, replaces the original encoded value in the request with a url to the new disk location. That url is actually what is saved to the database not the original base 64 encode sent. I hope I make it clearly how I am saving the photo

Comment: Well, in that case it is fairly straightforward, just use:  `get_post_meta( $order_id, $key, true)`. This should return you the url then you can just echo that to the `src` attribute of your image tag. I haven't tested it but, this should work. If you hit any snags, let me know.

Comment: I need to display the image at the WooCommerce order page itself that is the case/point. I already saved the image but how to show that image in all WooCommerce order pages. If there are WooCommerce hooks to use, if any, what are the parameters passed to the functions associated with those hooks (i.e., add_action('woocommerce_xxxx_xxxxx',  function-name) -> function-name(param)). I hope my point of view becomes more clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is called Woocommerce visual guide that contains some hooks that can be used to add content to various Woocommerce pages [WooCommerce Hooks Guide](https://premmerce.com/woocommerce-hooks-guide/) I found also others hooks that could be used to adjust the admin previews for order like `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details` and `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end`